# Angular : How to update a recursive directives scope/models

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I'm using a recursive directive to render a nested comment tree. Basically parent comments can have children comments and each children comment can have it's own child comments.

Each comment also has a reply field and makes a post request to my back end API.

My directive code:

```
commentTree.directive("tree", function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {parent: '=', onReply: '&'},
    template:
      '<ul>' +
          '<li ng-repeat="comment in parent">' +
              '<p>{{ comment.body }}</p>' +
              '<label>by {{ comment.submitter }}</label><label>@ {{ comment.created_at | date : "MM/dd @ h:mma" }}</label>' +
              '<form>' +
                '<label>Comment: </label><textarea ng-model="commentBody"></textarea>' +
                '<button ng-click="onReply({comment : comment, commentBody: commentBody})" class="btn btn-default">Reply</button>' +
              '</form>' +
              '<tree parent="comment.comments" on-reply="onReply({comment : comment, commentBody: commentBody})"></tree>' +
          '</li>' +
      '</ul>',
    compile: function(tElement, tAttr, transclude) {
      var contents = tElement.contents().remove();
      var compiledContents;
      return function(scope, iElement, iAttr) {
        if(!compiledContents) {
            compiledContents = $compile(contents, transclude);
        }
        compiledContents(scope, function(clone, scope) {
                 iElement.append(clone);
        });
      };
    }
  };
});
```

`parent` refers to the parent comment objects for that level, where each comment has a `comments` attribute which holds all of it's children comments. My theory is that there isn't any listener bound to this parent whenever the post request happens. In my controller,

```
$http.post("/api/comments", { comment: { body: comment , story_id: $routeParams.id }}).
      success(function(createdComment) {
        $scope.allComments.push(createdComment);
      }
    )
```

I'm guessing this doesn't work because the directive doesn't know how to link it up? Not really sure, any hints would be appreciated.

To clarify: I'm calling my Directive in HTML like so:

`<tree parent="allComments on-reply="reply(data)"></tree>`